# Error builtin:list-members on trying auto complete in mysql workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

Till yesterday auto complete was working in mysql workbench. Today getting below error on trying auto complete(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>).
Kindly help to resolve it if you have an idea.

[image]

Comment: Have you changed anything wrt. MySQL Workbench, e.g. an xml file, removed or renamed a file or folder etc.? Also look in the log to see any registered errors (see Help -> Show Log File).

Comment: I haven't changed any xml file or didn't rename file or folder. Did some import and export operations earlier.
Error which I read in log file is  [ERR][WBContext]: WBContext: exception in flush idle task: Exception:

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I restarted MySQL Workbench and now its working fine.

Answer (score 4):

It appears this is a known bug in MySQL workbench since 2018: [bugs.mysql.com](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=91859)...

1. Others have had success from rolling back to version 6.3.10. The bug is still present in the current version 8.0.23.
2. Another potential solution is delete the .column_widths file in:
   `[username]\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\cache`

*Ironically Mysql Workbench's .column_widths appear to be a sqlite version 3 file*

Answer (score 0):

I believe you corrupted your Workbench installation somehow, so the easiest way to fix that is to re-install the application.